# Use Ajax vs JSONP for cross domain data submission in sencha touch 2?

Tags: ajax, extjs, sencha-touch-2, jsonp

So I've done quite a bit of reading on stackoverflow and found a lot of question about how to do cross domain calls with either ajax post or jsonp. I know how to do that in both ways but let's do a reality check:

1. AJAX Post, if I use phonegap to compile the package, cross domain call is automatically availability . Or iframe wrapper etc can be used to hack around the security constraint.
2. use JSONP format, it's HTTP GET but I get cross domain capability for free as that's what JSONP is for. The data to be posted will be passed as a parameter value instead of being a payload as in an HTTP POST request.

Now my question is that is there a best practice/preferred way among the two? Pros and Cons?

Personally I don't see a practical difference between two. i.e. in a non-encrypted request, both POST or GET expose everything in clear text anyway, so they are just same piece of text arranged in different formats. My main concerns are around extension to make the connection secure and spam proof but there could be other stuffs that I probably should be mindful about as well - educate me please! E.g. easeness to add HTTPS over SSL or if I want to restrict who can send request to my server. I'm new to web technology (i.e. defined standards, protocols, frameworks) but am reasonably experienced on general development/computer science topics.

Comment: Depending on the size of the form you're posting, GET has size limits that are fairly low.

Comment: Size limit as for the overall size (in bytes) of the request or size of params (as in say number of characters allowed in passing values)?

Comment: You can't pass "bytes" in the query string, so, characters.